# DDD. Read directly from repository or using a entity?

Tags: .net, wcf, domain-driven-design

I'm developing a backend for a new system and I'll try to use DDD. I've defined my DDD entities in a Core-project and I read those entities from a persistence layer using the repository pattern.

I need a WCF service so my clients can access the backend. To and from this WCF service am I sending/receiving DTOs.

Lets say I have a typical Order, Orderrows scenario. In my WCF service I declare a function

```
IEnumerable<DTO.OrderRows> GetOrderRowsForOrder(DTO.Order o)
```

I need advice how to implement this method. I have two different choices.

1. Use my domain-object to read the orderrows.

   ```
   Core.Order order = _orderRepository.GetById(o.Id);
   IEnumerable<Core.OrderRow> orderRows = order.GetOrderRows();
   IEnumerable<DTO.OrderRows> dtos = orderRows.Select(x => x.ToDTO());

   return dtos;
   ```
2. Directly use the repository to read the orderrows.

   ```
   IEnumerable<Core.OrderRow> orderRows = _orderRowsRepository.GetOrderRowsForOrder(o.Id);
   IEnumerable<DTO.OrderRows> dtos = orderRows.Select(x => x.ToDTO());

   return dtos;
   ```

To me choice 1 looks more 'object-oriented', but choice no. 2 looks simpler and more effective.

My question is, which one to use when using DDD? Is it appropriate to use DDD here?

(This is of course a simple sample, but what if I need to get orderrows for a list of orders?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on your aggregate roots:

1. If Order is an aggregate root that contains the order rows, then `Order` should have a property `OrderRows` that will always be filled when you read an order. So there would be no "inefficiency" involved when getting the order rows from an order, because they will already be in memory.
2. If OrderRow is an aggregate root in itself, then there would be *no* `OrderRows` property or `GetOrderRows` method on `Order`. Instead you would use the `OrderRowsRepository` to get all order rows for the order, similar to what you outlined in your second example.

Answer (score 2):

I have been using number 2 but recently changed my mind more too that of number 1. The reason for this is that if you use 2 the repositories will eventually get littered with all kind of methods for asking the repository of things that the domain object (entity) should know about and be able to answer. In your own words; it's more object oriented.

Comment: As the context is explicitly Domain Driven Design, I disagree with your answer. The definition of the Aggregate Roots is the deciding factor here.

Comment: I've read up on aggregate roots and it's makes sense. But how about my second question, is DDD appropriate to use here?

Comment: @ErikZ: It really depends on your application. DDD is not something you apply to a small part of your application. If you choose to use DDD, this choice drives the complete architecture of your domain model and of the surrounding code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Core.Order is your aggregate root, you will already have a property in it for OrderRows such as

```
public class Order
{
    public IEnumerable<Core.OrderRows> Rows { get; set; }

}
```

So choice #1 with a slight modification to call the Rows property rather than querying with GetOrderRows() would be appropriate.

```
Core.Order order = _orderRepository.GetById(o.Id);
IEnumerable<Core.OrderRow> orderRows = order.Rows;
IEnumerable<DTO.OrderRows> dtos = orderRows.Select(x => x.ToDTO());

return dtos;
```